# Limit the results of {{#each a in b}}

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a Model called Course that has an array variable called users. Is there a way to just limit the results of, let say, IDs from users rather than the {{#each}} rendering every single id? 
Such that

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="course">
{{#each user in users 5}} 
    {{user.name}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Will show the first 5 IDs rather than every single id stored in users? 
Here is the Ember-data model that I am using

```
App.Course = DS.Model.extend({
  //Attributes
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  //Relations
  users: DS.hasMany('App.User'),
});
```

I tried multiple times at creating a registerHelper, but where it always seems to go wrong is when an 'a in b' is present.
Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than modifying the `#each` helper you could take a different approach to show only a limited amount of items when looping over the array with the `#each` helper.

See this for a possible implementation:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      Ember.Object.create({id:1, name:'Red'}),
      Ember.Object.create({id:2, name:'Green'}),
      Ember.Object.create({id:3, name:'Blue'})
    ];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  limitedContent: function() {
    return this.get('content').splice(0, 2);
  }.property('content')
});
```

The `.property('content')` defines a binding to the controller's content and takes care that the `#each` helper rerenders when the `content` changes.

And then in your template you loop over the `limitedContent` rather then the `content`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="course">
  {{#each color in limitedContent}} 
    {{color.name}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

And here a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ajopah/7/edit) that show the concept mentioned.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not even think of going to the controller for this.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the method in the accepted method, but ran into an issue with it.

The problem lay in that using splice in ember modifies the underlying data:

```
filtered: function() {
    return this.get('content').splice(0,2);
}.property('content'),
```

splice removes the elements from the underlying content.
A better method is to use Ember's built-in slice function, changing the above code into

```
filtered: function() {
    return this.get('content').slice(0,2);
}.property('content'),
```

And that's it, now it doesn't modify the underlying array, because slice returns a new array and leaves the underlying data untouched.

JSBin showing that splice modifies underlying data:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ridixawimugo/1/

JSBin with the fixed solution:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/voceye/1/